# OutOfMemoryError in eclipse plug-in

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, out-of-memory

I keep on getting `OutOfMemoryError` with my eclipse plug-in. All I get is the message in the console.
Any clues?

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2012-03-15 00:03:44.426
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`: PermGen space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to increase the permgen space. Assuming you are using Sun jdk, try "-XX:MaxPermSize=128m". 128m is an example, you might need lesser or more depending on your configuration.